# Validating Date Prompt To be less than Current Date OBIEE

Tags: oracle, validation, analysis, obiee

I have a requirement to create two validations on the date prompt:

1) The From Date has to be less than To Date

2) The To Date has to be less than or equal to current date

I created a conditional analysis wherein From Date is < To Date, which works, but when I try to create an advanced filter wherein @To_Date <= Current_Date I am getting an error.

> Error getting drill information: SELECT date'2016-08-24' saw_0 FROM "Workforce Management - Processed Time Cards Real Time" WHERE(date'@{To_Date}' <= (SELECT VALUEOF("CURRENT_DATE_REP_OTBI") FROM "Workforce Management - Processed Time Cards Real Time" FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY))

If anyone can help solve this, it'd be really helpful! 
Thanks

Comment: Is "current_date" supposed to be an Oracle system-provided date? Then it should be `sysdate`. Also, (not being familiar with OBIEE I have to ask)... if it all works exactly as in the underlying database, then `to_date <= sysdate` will fail if `to_date` has a time-of-day component that is later than the exact moment when the query is run.

Comment: @mathguy hey, yeah..it will return 0 rows and consequently should display an error message...so that is what i was aiming for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a default value when referencing presentation variables in logical SQL queries or formulas. Especially if these are dates.

I created an analysis based on the following LogicalSQL and it worked.

> SELECT date'2016-08-26' saw_0 from "subject_area" WHERE (date
>   @{to_date}{'2016-08-26'} < CURRENT_DATE)

Notice the following:

- The presentation variable @{to_date} goes with a default value (noted by the second curly brackets). This helps OBIEE to validate the query. **Failing to add the default value will give you the "getting drill information" error.**
- Instead of a session RPD variable, you can use CURRENT_DATE. It simplifies the query.

The above query will return the date in the SELECT clause, but if the to_date is greater than CURRENT_DATE will return no data.

Comment: I thought so too, but I realized the problem was I was either putting a condition of sql expression as "select current date from... " or I tried to directly put current_date as value.
I could fix it by only putting CURRENT_DATE in sql expression.
Thanks!